# CORS Error in a working setup while trying to authenticate using Google+ API in React/Node setup

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I was implementing the Oauth2.0 authentication using Google. I used react-google-login npm on the frontend to authenticate the user using Google Oauth2.0. I successfully created the CLient-id and secret under google cloud platform for my project, along with the URI as needed.

The frontend is running on default localhost:3000 and backend (node/express) running on localhost:9001 with proxy enabled on frontend to redirect the request to backend.

I was able to authenticate using Google more than 2 dozen times last night as i was working on the backend siginIn contoller. I was also able to add the user to my Mongodb after successful authentication from Google.

All of a sudden, i was getting CORS error which is a bit strange as none of the code or Google configs were changed.

My Google config looks as follows.[image: Google 0auth2.0 Configs]

My code on the frontend is still successfully redirecting the user to Google for authentication. Its also generating the right google credentials.

SignIn Component Code snippet passing the info to responseGoogle which resides in withLogin HOC Parent Component.

```
            <GoogleLogin
            clientId={GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}
            buttonText="Google"
            render={(renderProps) => (
              <button onClick={renderProps.onClick} style={customStyle}>
                <img className="googleBtn" src={googleIcon} alt="GMAIL ICON" />
              </button>
            )}
            onSuccess={responseGoogle}
            onFailure={responseGoogle}
            cookiePolicy={"single_host_origin"}
          />
```

withLogin HOC Parent Component dispatching the info to Redux thunk.

```
const responseGoogle = (res) => setGoogleResp(res);

    useEffect(() => {
      googleResp?.error &&
        setValues({ ...values, serverError: "GOOGLE LOGIN FAILED" });
      googleResp?.tokenId && dispatchGoogleSignInDataToBackend()
    }, [googleResp]);


    const dispatchGoogleSignInDataToBackend=async ()=>{
      const data=await dispatch(allActions.googleSignInAction(googleResp,whoLoggedIn));
      if (data.error) {
        setValues({ ...values, serverError: data.error, success: false });
      } else {
        const {
          email,
          name,
          _id,
          role,
          listOfEmailOfAllClientsForLawyerLogin,
        } = data.userCred;
        saveJwtToLocalStorage(
          data.token,
          { name, email, _id, role, listOfEmailOfAllClientsForLawyerLogin },
          () => {
            setValues({
              email,
              serverError: false,
              success: true,
            });
          }
        );
      }
    }
```

I am sending the appropriate CORS header in the request to the backend.

```
export const dataHeaders = {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" :"*"
  };
```

Redux thunk code:-

```
export const googleSignInAction=(googleResp,whoLoggedIn)=>{
  console.log("Login Success: currentUser:", googleResp);

  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: SIGNIN_LOADING });
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        `${API_URL}/googlesignin`,
        {
          googleResp,
          whoLoggedIn
        },
        {
          headers: dataHeaders,
        }
      );
      console.log("response inside googleSignInAction", response);
            // CHANGED COZ OF ESLINT WARNING.

      if (
        response.status === 201 &&
        Object.keys(response.data).includes("token") &&
        Object.keys(response.data).includes("userCred")
      ) {
        dispatch({ type: SIGNIN_SUCCESS, data: response.data });
        return response.data;
      } else {
        dispatch({ type: SIGNIN_FAILED });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({ type: SIGNIN_FAILED });

      return error.response.data;
    }
  };
}
```

API URL Points to following:-

```
export const API_URL="http://localhost:9001/api";
```

No request is reaching the backend because of CORS error.

Frontend receiving the Correct Response from Google Post authentication.
[image]

Errors on the Frontend.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried clearing the cache, cookies on the chrome browser. But still didnt work.

Comment: either add CORS headers to backend response or serve frontend and backend from same port

Comment: I have enabled the CORS on the backend using npm package. I have tried enabling the cors on the specific route with the new options. Please let me know if i am missing anything here.  const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();

app.use(cors());

var corsOptions = {
  "origin": "*",
  "methods": "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
  "preflightContinue": true,
  "optionsSuccessStatus": 204
} app.options("/googlesignin", cors(corsOptions)) // enable pre-flight request for DELETE request

router.post("/googlesignin", cors(corsOptions), authUserUsingGoogle);

Comment: In case your app goes public, `origin:*` is not secure. It should point to the front end app

Comment: Yeah you are right, i have added whitelist configs under the cors-option which includes the frontend ip and port.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers will first send a pre-flight request to check CORS. In your backend code, you have to allow the front-end host and port. In this case localhost:3000.
The reason you are getting the cors error is bacause its on two different ports.
But if proper cors response is given by backend (port 9000), it will resolve.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Clearing the browser cookies and cache made everything work again. googlesignin is working without cors error. I have added following line of code to serve all static files from backend to frontend.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../frontend/public')));
```